# Schedule notification in flutter using firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

How can I schedule the flutter notification with Firebase to run in the background even if the mobile phone is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check out Firebase cloud messaging if you want to make notifications for marketing purposes. If you want to store notifications locally check this video out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlgVI4dQC4E

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for this task depending on your specific scheduling requirements.

1. Schedule a local notification, which is for example triggered by the users themselves (e.g. some reminder or timer). In this case, the [Flutter local notifications plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) does the trick.

These options make use of the Firebase cloud messaging service, for setup follow [this guide](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/):

2. For scheduling notifications once in a while (e.g. for marketing purposes), the cloud messaging tab in Firebase offers a user interface for scheduling notifications.
3. Schedule notifications repeating at a fixed interval with cloud functions. This can be done by utilizing the [cronjob-like scheduling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) functionality.
4. Schedule notifications starting from a certain point in time (with a delay) using cloud functions combined with cloud tasks like described [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).
5. A more complicated way of implementing tasks is described [here](https://fireship.io/lessons/cloud-functions-scheduled-time-trigger/), but I would not recommend it if you want an elegant solution.

In the end, scheduling notifications comes down to implementing a scheduling mechanism for cloud functions.

Answer (score -1):

TLDR: You can use the [firebase_notification_scheduler](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_notification_scheduler) package to schedule notifications in Flutter.

**Creating API Keys**

This plugin makes use of a Rapid API service. You need to Signup for the Firebase Notification Scheduler Rapid API and get API Key from [here](https://rapidapi.com/magno-labs-magno-labs-default/api/firebase-notification-scheduler).
Then create your authentication key [from here](http://fns-registration.magnolabs.in/) to work with package

**Initialising Package**

```
final FirebaseNotificationScheduler firebaseNotificationScheduler =  
    FirebaseNotificationScheduler(  
        authenticationKey: <YOUR-RAPID-API-KEY> ,
        rapidApiKey:  <YOUR-AUTHENTICATION-KEY>
        );
```

**Scheduling a notification**

```
//Schedules a notification to the topic 'any' for next minute
    final String _payload = {
      "to": "/topics/any",
      "notification": {
        "title": "Title of Your Notification",
        "body": "Body of Your Notification"
      },
      "data": {"key_1": "Value for key_1", "key_2": "Value for key_2"}
    }.toString();
    final DateTime _now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    final DateTime _dateTimeInUtc = _now.add(const Duration(minutes: 1));

    await firebaseNotificationScheduler.scheduleNotification(
        payload: _payload, dateTimeInUtc: _dateTimeInUtc);
```

Comment: have you scheduled the notification?